# Android, how to send array[] of my own classes via Intens

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent

I have problem with starting new Activity in my app.In shorthand it will be app of sound effects(animals,people,fun...)

In my MainActivity there is button with onClick method

```
    public void clic(View v) {
       Intent newIntent=new Intent(this,AktivityImage.class);
       newIntent.putExtra("id", aFactory.getAnimals());
       startActivity(newIntent);
}
```

Method aFactory.getAnimals() returns array of my own class:

```
    public Entit[] getAnimals(){
      return aArrayAnimals;
}
```

Class Entit is primitive, just constructor and 2 getters.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Entit implements Serializable{

private int aSound;
private int aImage;

public Entit(int paIdImage,int paIdSound){

    aImage=paIdImage;
    aSound=paIdSound;
}



public int getImage(){
    return aImage;
}


public int getSound(){
    return aSound;
}
```

}

And there is a problem, in class AktivityImage

```
    private Entit[] aEntity;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.sounds_layout);

      aIntent=this.getIntent();
      aEntity=(Entit[]) aIntent.getSerializableExtra("id");
```

Some tips? Thanks to all.

Comment: Should work. Which exception do you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have explained you could use Pacelable or Serializable both works the same way except in case of Bundle api. Bundle accept serializable and parcelable objects + it accepts parcelable array/arraylist/SparseArray but it doest accept array of serilaizable object as it is. Easiest way is create a Transport class ( again serializable ) some what like

```
   public static class Transport implements Serializable{
        public Entit[] data;

        public Transport(Entit[] data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
```

And the modify make an instance of the Transport class and put it in the bundle

```
Intent newIntent=new Intent(this,AktivityImage.class);
newIntent.putExtra("id", new Transport(aFactory.getAnimals()));
startActivity(newIntent);
```

And when you read read as a Serializable casted into Transport and takeout the actual data

```
aIntent=this.getIntent();
aEntity=((Transport) aIntent.getSerializableExtra("id")).data;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to pass an object through intents, they should implement the `Parcelable` interface.  [Here's the relevant doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).  With your class, it should be very simple - all you have is two integers, which fit directly into a parcel without any extra work.

Any object that implements `Parcelable` can be placed into a bundle (and therefor also placed inside an `Intent`).  Use one of the various getter/setter methods in `Intent` to set and retrieve your data.

Comment: Using Parcelables is preferable from a performance perspective, but it is definitely not a requirement. Serializables will do the job as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your class is going to be that simple, and you have a fixed number of Sound Effects then you might want to use Enums instead since Enums are automatically serializable and they can be stored in Intents and Bundles with overwhelming ease.

```
enum SoundEffects {PIANO, DRUM, ....}

SoundEffects mSound = SoundEffects.DRUM; 

Intent intent = new Intent(); 

intent.putExtra("Sound", mSound); 

Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 

bundle.putSerializable("Sound", mSound);
```

and there you go.

Also, primitives like ints and doubles can be passed into Enums and Enums can have getters and setters so that won't be a problem... so using the previous example you could do

enum SoundEffects {PIANO(10, 20), DRUM(25,30), ....}

but then you have to add an constructor to your enum to accept these values.

Answer (score 0):

Throught : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

you can use putExtras and getExtras respectively from sender to receiver. Extras can range from int[] to Serializables.